# Trying to change the name that appears under the launcher icon on my iOS phone

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a XF application. I thought I had changed everything but the name that appears on the phone under the app icon when I try on my phone locally is still an old name.

When running Xamarin on a Mac OS, does anyone know where to go to change this name for the iOS app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Info.plist` change the value for keys [CFBundleName](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundlename) & [CFBundleDisplayName](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundledisplayname).

```xml
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>MY_APP_NAME</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>MY_APP_NAME</string>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to do this by using Textedit.  I didn't find a way to change DisplayName on the screen.  Works now.  Will accept Q.

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio 17.0.4 I just double clicked on the Info.plist in the Solution Explorer.  On the Application tab there is an Application Name field where you can change the name that appears under the icon.  This ends up changing the MY_APP_NAME under the CFBundleDisplayName.